# Finding numbers in an array are in sequential order or not

Tags: c

I have an array with 5 elements (1024,1025,1026,1027,1028).How can I check these elements are in sequential or not.I could do the same if array has even number of elements.

Comment: Iterate through the array?

Comment: increment array pointer by 1 every time till end & check for its result...

Comment: you should define _`sequential`_, because `..., 8, 4, 2, 1` sequence is also sequential... Or by saying `sequential` you mean just `ordered` ? In that case I posted an aswer if you want to find if list is ordered in ascending/descending way.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the array and ensure the previous member (if it exists) is equal to the current minus `1`.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
     if (arr[i - 1] != arr[i] - 1) {
          // It's not sequential.
          break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Why not start with `i = 1` and lose the `i > 0` check?

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate through the array:

```
bool is_sequence(int *arr, int size) 
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < (size - 1); i++)
    {
        if((arr[i] + 1) != arr[i])
            /* array is not sequential */
            return false;
    }

    /* array is sequential */
    return true;
}

<...>
if(is_sequence(my_array, 5))
    printf("sequential!"
else
    printf("not sequential");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the two neighboring numbers and you have to do the same thing for many times. So, a loop is necessary. An easy programme is as followed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[5]={1024,1025,1026,1027,1028};
    int i,s;
    for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)
    {
        if(a[i]+1 != a[i+1])
        {  s=-1; break; }
        else
        {  s=0; }
    }
    if(s=0)
    { printf("sequential."); }
    else
    { printf("not sequential."); }
}
```

I hope that my answer could help you. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yingli Yan.This is the answer I was searching for

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this solution (if by saying `sequential` you mean just `ordered`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isArraySequential(int * array, int size) {
    int isAscendingFirst;
    int isAscendingCurrent;
    int isChangeFound = 0;
    int i;

    // arrays of length 0/1/2 are assumed to be sequential
    if (size < 3)
      return 1;

    for (i=1; i < size; i++) {
      // in case there is a change
      if (array[i] != array[i-1]) {
          isAscendingCurrent = (array[i] > array[i-1]);
          // on first change
          if (!isChangeFound) {
            isChangeFound = 1;
            isAscendingFirst = isAscendingCurrent;
          }
          // on subsequent changes
          else {
            if (isAscendingFirst != isAscendingCurrent)
              return 0;
          }
      }
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(){
  int array1[4] = {1, 1, 0, -1};
  int array2[4] = {2, 2, 2, 2};
  int array3[4] = {1, 2, 4, 3};

  printf("Is array1 sequential ? %d\n", isArraySequential(array1, 4));
  printf("Is array2 sequential ? %d\n", isArraySequential(array2, 4));
  printf("Is array3 sequential ? %d\n", isArraySequential(array3, 4));

  return 0;
}
```

because in general sequential array can be in `ascending` OR `descending` order and this must be taken into account. Also there are corner cases - arrays of length 0/1/2 are always sequential (i am not sure about length 0).

**EDIT:** I've fixed code for situation when first array elements are with same values. Now it should work OK.